Does Google OAuth no longer review Fit API Scope?
We are proving a service using the Google Fit API to our customers for 3 years,
but currently the service is not working because we did not request the necessary OAuth Scope change within the deadline.
In order to restore service, we have submitted additional authentication requests for the two scopes below.
Fitness API ../auth/fitness.activity.read
Fitness API ../auth/fitness.activity.write
We are wondering if the review request we submitted is currently being processed.
I am also concerned that the policy below will also apply to review of the scope of our submission, which will result in our submitted request being denied review.
"Fit APIs are being deprecated and will no longer be a part of our verification workflow beginning May 1, 2024"
Does anyone have information about this issue?
I am trying to search for relevant information on the internet an developer documentation,but couldn't find any detailed information.

Do you have more informations now? I am struggling with the same. I have an additional Info: "Google Fit APIs are being deprecated and beginning May 1, 2024 we are no longer accepting application verification requests for Google Fit API scopes. Any application verification request containing only Google Fit API scopes will be auto closed and may not receive any further communication from the verification team.
Existing access to Google Fit API scopes will not be immediately impacted. For additional information and support..."

They are shutting down Google Fit why would you want to create an app that uses it?

The Google Fit APIs, including the Google Fit REST API, will no longer be available after June 30, 2025. As of May 1, 2024, developers cannot sign up to use these APIs.


For instructions on which API or platform to migrate to, visit the Health Connect migration guide. For a comparison of Health Connect with the Google Fit APIs and the Fitbit Web APIs, visit the Health Connect comparison guide.


Learn more about Health Connect and how to integrate with the API.


We have already been providing services using Google Fit in our app for a long time. Currently, the service is not working properly due to incorrect scope settings on the OAuth consent screen. We are also preparing to migrate to Google Health Connect. In order to provide services normally until the migration is completed.  a review request for correct scope has been requested, and verification is still in progress.

Unfortunately it will be impossible for new apps to request for verification. Long standing apps however can appeal provided that they have transition plans set for them to work on.
